# SQL Recursion Ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Heres my query:

```
;with cte as ( select RMT_Baseline_Id, B1.CIIdentifier, RMT_ParentBaselineId, cast('' as varchar(max)) as [path], 0 as level, row_number()over(partition by RMT_ParentBaselineId 
order by B1.CIIdentifier desc) / power(10.0,0) as x 
from tbl_RMTRiskIssue R1 
inner join tbl_Baseline B1 on B1.Id=R1.RMT_Baseline_Id 
where RMT_ParentBaselineId is null 
union all 
select t.RMT_Baseline_Id, B2.CIIdentifier, t.RMT_ParentBaselineId, [path]+B2.CIIDentifier+'-->', level+1, x + row_number()over(partition by t.RMT_ParentBaselineId 
order by B2.CIIdentifier desc) / power(10.0,level+1)  
from cte 
join tbl_RMTRiskIssue t on cte.RMT_Baseline_Id = t.RMT_ParentBaselineId 
inner join tbl_Baseline B2 on B2.Id=cte.RMT_Baseline_Id ) 
SELECT x, b.ciidentifier,[path] from cte 
inner join tbl_Baseline B on B.Id =cte.RMT_Baseline_id 
WHERE B.thisbaseline IN(615) 
ORDER BY x
```

Here's my results

```
x                       CIIdentifier path
694.100000000000000000  RA.0016      RI.0001-->
694.110000000000000000  RA.0008      RI.0001-->RA.0016-->
694.120000000000000000  RA.0015      RI.0001-->RA.0016-->
```

Can any one tell me why line 3 doesnt come before line 2? Its supposed to sort by CIIdentifier DESC but its not

I think x needs to be constructed differently for the children so 694.11 is RA.0015 and 694.12 is RA.0008 but cant work it out, the CTE is ordered by CIIdentifier desc but seems to be ignored, if I change it to ASC then the results are the same which Im finding bizarre

Thanks

Comment: not sure how to bump this but can anyone tell me why i dont get x=694.11 for RA.0008 and 694.12 for RA.0015 when the order by is CIIDENTFIER DESC?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ORDER BY x` forces the entire dataset to order by that number and 694.110000000000000000  < 694.120000000000000000. For a quick review of how order by works, click [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

> The ORDER BY keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default. To sort the records in a descending order, you can use the DESC keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It's ordering by `x` right here !

Replace the (last) line `ORDER BY x` by `ORDER BY B1.CIIdentifier desc`

Advice: write SQL keywords in uppercase, it makes it easier to be understood for persons who doesn't know the meaning of your columns and what you're trying exactly to do !

`FROM` `SELECT` `INNER` `JOIN`ORDERBY` ...

**EDIT** Or just remove the last line of your query

Comment: I understand that! but x is being constructed wrong? RA.0008 and RA.0015 are children of RA.0016 but I need them the other way round, RA.0015 should come before RA.0008. A fourth line might be RA.0010 with no children so its not as simple as sorting by CIIdentifier, its a recursive query!

Comment: have you tried to remove the last line and verify your output ?

Comment: yep, get random results then, I think x needs to be constructed differently for the children so 694.11 is RA.0015 and 694.12 is RA.0008 but cant work it out, the CTE is CIIdentifier desc but seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The final select statement is selecting from your CTE, the CTE is ordered by the B1.CIIdentifier, however the final select is ordering by X.

Remove the un-needed select in the CTE builder, and order by the right field at the end.